# Spring validation messages not picked up from resource bunlde

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have custom Spring validator where I'm rejecting values:

`ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "lastName", "field.required");`

Also, inside `/resources` maven's folder I have Resource Bundle  called `messages.properties`. This file contains custom message used in validation:

`field.required=Required field`

I registered this message source in Spring configuration:

```
 <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
 </bean>
```

In my controller I'm manually calling validator:

`myValidator.validate(myObject, bindingResult);`

The problem is that `bindingResult` object doesn't contain custom error messages from `messages.properties` file.

In other words this is `null`: `bindingResult.getFieldErrors().get(0).getDefaultMessage()` but should be `Required field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to call `getDefaultMessage()`. You should instead take the `FieldError` (which extends `DefaultMessageSourceResolvable` and implements `DefaultMessageSourceResolvable`) and pass it to your `messageSource`:

```
messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, LOCALE);
```

Regarding `getDefaultMessage()` returning `null`: I've never used this interface, but looking at the code for `ValidationUtils`, the `defaultMessage` doesn't seem to be what you think it is. You're using:

```
rejectIfEmpty(Errors errors, String field, String errorCode);
```

rather than

```
rejectIfEmpty(Errors errors, String field, String errorCode, String defaultMessage);
```

It is this last parameter that ends up being a part of the `FieldError` instance in the binding result. Since you've not passed a value here, it will be null in the `FieldError`.